# htaccess change directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, directory

Hi i need to use this existing htaccess located on the root folder.
I now need to create a new directory /testfolder/ to become http://www.companydomain.com/testfolder/ where all the files of the root will be located.

How can I make this happen with this existing htaccess? Much appreciated your help in advance!

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/(.*).html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [L,R=301]

# 301
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.companydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .? http://www.companydomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^Sportsbooks\/(.*).html$ Sportsbooks\/$1\/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

This `.htaccess` file will redirect `http://example.com/file.html` to `http://example.com/folder1/file.html`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !folder1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/folder1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: hi im having an infinite loop redirection